# Eric joisel origami

Tags: origami

How can I make the Viking origami model by Eric joisel

It's diagrams are nowhere given
I searched at many places but no instructions or tutorials were available

Can anyone help me out with the Viking origami model

Comment: See [this meta discussion](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/whats-the-distinction-between-recipe-and-technique-questions) on why your "recipe" question isn't a great fit for this SE.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that Eric Joisel is an accomplished artist in origami. His creations bring thousands of dollars for each work.

As such, it's unlikely that you'll find any means of creating duplicates of his work, especially considering the complexity of the models.

It is also likely that anyone who creates an exact duplicate of his work may be in violation of intellectual property laws.

[image: eric joisel viking]

Comment: Kindly give instructions for the Lord of the rings origami models

Comment: although your request would fall into the category of requiring another post as it is a different (albeit related) question, my research shows that those models are also artist creations with no instructions available. Consider to use your preferred search engine with the terms "origami instructions" followed by the type of model you seek.